# Count number of sundays in current month

Tags: python

How can I get the numberof  Sundays of the current month in Python?

Anyone got any idea about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gives you the number of sundays in a current month as you wanted:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

In [367]: len([1 for i in calendar.monthcalendar(datetime.now().year,
                                  datetime.now().month) if i[6] != 0])
Out[367]: 4
```

Answer (score 7):

I happened to need a solution for this, but was unsatisfactory with the solutions here, so I came up with my own:

```
import calendar

year = 2016
month = 3
day_to_count = calendar.SUNDAY

matrix = calendar.monthcalendar(year,month)

num_days = sum(1 for x in matrix if x[day_to_count] != 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
day = datetime.date(today.year, today.month, 1)
single_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

sundays = 0
while day.month == today.month:
    if day.weekday() == 6:
        sundays += 1
    day += single_day

print 'Sundays:', sundays
```

Answer (score 4):

My take: (saves having to worry about being in the right month etc...)

```
from calendar import weekday, monthrange, SUNDAY

y, m = 2012, 10

days = [weekday(y, m, d+1) for d in range(*monthrange(y, m))]
print days.count(SUNDAY)
```

Or, as [@mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) has pointed out, you can do away with the list-comp, and wrap it all up as a generator:

```
sum(1 for d in range(*monthrange(y,m)) if weekday(y,m,d+1)==SUNDAY)
```

And I suppose, you could throw in a:

```
from collections import Counter
days = Counter(weekday(y, m, d + 1) for d in range(*monthrange(y, m)))
print days[SUNDAY]
```

Comment: Why iterate twice?  `print sum(1 for d in range(*monthrange(y,m)) if weekday(y,m,d+1)==SUNDAY)`

Comment: @mgilson Was keeping it simple - I actually had `sum(1...)` open in the interpreter but changed it back to a list-comp and .count for posting here :)

Comment: I am not sure that this works any more.  `monthrange(y, m)` seems to return a tuple being the first day of the month and the number of days in the month.  So for example, `monthrange(2013, 2) `returns (4, 28).  range of this then gives only the days from 4, 5, ...28.  
`y, m = 2013, 2;  
days = [weekday(y, m, d+1) for d in range(*monthrange(y, m))];  
print (days.count(SUNDAY));` gives 3 not 4.  I used instead `len([d for d in range(monthrange(y, m)[1]) if weekday(y, m, d+1)==SUNDAY]) ` which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another example using `calendar` and `datetime`:

```
import datetime
import calendar
today = datetime.date.today()
m = today.month
y = today.year
sum(1 for week in calendar.monthcalendar(y,m) if week[-1])
```

Perhaps a slightly faster way to do it would be:

```
first_day,month_len = monthrange(y,m)
date_of_first_sun = 1+6-first_day
print sum(1 for x in range(date_of_first_sun,month_len+1,7))
```

Comment: I would love to improve on this if you leave some feedback :).

Comment: I think this could be wrong in some situations. What if 1st and 2nd of the month are Saturday and Sunday? Then 29th and 30th will be Saturday and Sunday as well.

Comment: @AlexanderStefanov -- So?  I'm not seeing your point here ... (this could be wrong was clear enough, but I don't understand your rational)

Comment: @AlexanderStefanov -- Why do you insist that my algorithm will only count 4?  Try it for last month -- (`sum(1 for week in calendar.monthcalendar(2012,9) if week[-1])
`.  It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ISO week numbers:

```
from datetime import date
bom = date.today().replace(day=1)                 # first day of current month
eom = (date(bom.year, 12, 31) if bom.month == 12 else
       (bom.replace(month=bom.month + 1) - 1))    # last day of current month
_, b_week, _ = bom.isocalendar()
_, e_week, e_weekday = eom.isocalendar()
num_sundays = (e_week - b_week) + (1 if e_weekday == 7 else 0)
```

In general for a particular day of the week (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday) the calculation is:

```
num_days = ((e_week - b_week) +
            (-1 if b_weekday > day else 0) +
            ( 1 if e_weekday >= day else 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar

MONTH = 10    
sundays = 0
cal = calendar.Calendar()

for day in cal.itermonthdates(2012, MONTH):
    if day.weekday() == 6 and day.month == MONTH:
        sundays += 1
```

PAY ATTENTION:
Here are the Calendar.itermonthdates's docs:

> Return an iterator for one month. The iterator will yield datetime.date
>   values and will always iterate through complete weeks, so it will yield
>   dates outside the specified month.

That's why `day.month == MONTH` is needed

If you want the weekdays to be in range 0-6, use `day.weekday()`,
if you want them to be in range 1-7, use `day.isoweekday()`

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

The following was inspired by @Lingson's answer, but I think it does lesser loops.

```
import calendar

def get_number_of_weekdays(year: int, month: int) -> list:
    main_calendar = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
    number_of_weeks = len(main_calendar)
    number_of_weekdays = []

    for i in range(7):
        number_of_weekday = number_of_weeks

        if main_calendar[0][i] == 0:
            number_of_weekday -= 1
        
        if main_calendar[-1][i] == 0:
            number_of_weekday -= 1

        number_of_weekdays.append(number_of_weekday)

    return sum(number_of_weekdays)  # In my application I needed the number of each weekday, so you could return just the list to do that.
```