# Pyrhon: Get days of month present in current month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with two columns number and day. I'm trying to get the frequency of particular days if `day` is `True`.

From `Monday - 0` to `sunday - 6` as per calendar.

For `1(Tuesday)` there are `4 Tuesdays` present in the month of `may`. 
Similarly for `6(Sunday)` there are `5 Sundays` in `may`.

df

```
    df= pd.DataFrame(data = {'number' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6'], 'day' : [True, False, False, False, True]}) 


        number  day
    0   1       True
    1   2       False
    2   3       False
    3   4       False
    4   6       True
```

My excepted output:

```
        number          day
    0   7,14,21,28      True
    1   2               False   
    2   3               False
    3   4               False
    4   3,10,17,24,31   True
```

Comment: Might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973691/count-number-of-sundays-in-current-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `Calendar`

```
from calendar import Calendar
a=np.array(Calendar().monthdayscalendar(2020,5))
l=[','.join(a[:,int(x)][a[:,int(x)]!=0].astype(str)) if y else x for x, y  in zip(df.number,df.day)]
['5,12,19,26', '2', '3', '4', '3,10,17,24,31']
df['number']=l
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is more general that the other, i.e. it computes days
for the **current** month, whenever you run this code.

Start from some preparatory computation:

```
# Start of the current month
dStart = pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0).rollback(pd.Timestamp.today().normalize())
# DataFrame for the current month, for now only "Date" column
mnth = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start=dStart,
    periods=dStart.daysinmonth)})
# Add "Day of Week" column
mnth['DoW'] = mnth.Date.dt.dayofweek
# Add "Day" column (as string)
mnth['Day'] = mnth.Date.dt.day.astype(str)
# Convert to list of days (for each DoW)
mnth = mnth.groupby('DoW').Day.apply(lambda s: ','.join(list(s)))
```

And to conditionally change each *number* in *df* it is enough to run
a **single** instruction:

```
df.number = df.apply(lambda row: mnth.loc[int(row.number)]
    if row.day else row.number, axis=1)
```

The result, for May 2020, is:

```
          number    day
0     5,12,19,26   True
1              2  False
2              3  False
3              4  False
4  3,10,17,24,31   True
```